# Exploding multiple dict columns and concatenating with original Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I export a Postgres SQL query to create a Pandas data frame `df` similar to the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'employee_id' : [123, 456, 789],
    'country_code' : ['US', 'CAN', 'MEX'],
    'sales' : [{'foo': 2, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 1},
               {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 2},
               {'foo': 7, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 4}],
    'expenses' : [{'red': 1, 'white': 0, 'blue': 3},
               {'red': 1, 'white': 0, 'blue': 1},
               {'red': 2, 'white': 2, 'blue': 2}]
})

df
 
    employee_id   country_code      sales                             expenses
0   123           US                {'foo': 2, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 1}    {'red': 1, 'white': 0, 'blue': 3}
1   456           CAN               {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 2}    {'red': 1, 'white': 0, 'blue': 1}
2   789           MEX               {'foo': 7, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 4}    {'red': 2, 'white': 2, 'blue': 2}
```

I would like to be able to explode ***both*** the `sales` and `expenses` columns so that their keys are separate columns.  Currently, I'm only able to explode ***one*** of these columns, as follows:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['sales'])
df
    foo bar baz
0   2   0   1
1   3   1   2
2   7   0   4
```

I'm not able to pass a list of columns to `pd.json.normalize()`.

Questions:

1. How do I explode both the `sales` and `expenses` columns?
2. After exploding both columns, how do I add back the other two columns (`employee_id` and `country_code`) from the original data frame?

The desired output is:

```
    employee_id   country_code   foo   bar   baz   red   white   blue
0   123           US             2     0     1     1     0       3
1   456           CAN            3     1     2     1     0       1
2   789           MEX            7     0     4     2     2       2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) along axis=1 with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
json_cols = ['sales','expenses']
result = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[col]) for col in json_cols],axis=1)
result = pd.concat([df.drop(json_cols,axis=1),result],axis=1)
```

Output:

result

```
    employee_id country_code    foo bar baz red white   blue
0   123         US               2   0   1   1   0       3 
1   456         CAN              3   1   2   1   0       1
2   789         MEX              7   0   4   2   2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the original dataframe, a variant would be:

```
cols = ['sales', 'expenses']

df = pd.concat([df]+[pd.json_normalize(df.pop(c)) for c in cols], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   employee_id country_code  foo  bar  baz  red  white  blue
0          123           US    2    0    1    1      0     3
1          456          CAN    3    1    2    1      0     1
2          789          MEX    7    0    4    2      2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   df.join(df.sales.apply(pd.Series))
    .join(df.expenses.apply(pd.Series))
    .drop(['sales','expenses'],axis=1)
    
    
       employee_id country_code  foo  bar  baz  red  white  blue
    0          123           US    2    0    1    1      0     3
    1          456          CAN    3    1    2    1      0     1
    2          789          MEX    7    0    4    2      2     2
```